# Integrability of the negative part

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $(f_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence of decreasing measurable functions that converges pointwise to $ f $. Suppose the negative part $(f^{-})_{n}$ of $f_{n}$   ($:=\max\lbrace- f_{n},0\rbrace$) is integrable:
$$\int_{X}(f^{-})_{n}\mu<\infty$$ for all $n$. Can we conclude that $f^{-}$ is also integrable?

Comment: What if $f_n = - \chi_{[-n,n]}$ and $f = -1$?

Comment: That should be $(f_n)^-.$ Also, shouldn't "sequence of decreasing measurable functions" be "point wise decreasing sequence of measurable functions"?